# Driver for Microstrain 3DM-GX3-35

Tags: ros, imu, microstrain

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know about a driver for the Microstrain 3DM-GX3-35 or
used the sensor on Linux? This is a Microstrain IMU with an integrated
GPS. The protocol for the 3DM-GX3-35 is different from the 3DM-GX3-25 so
the microstrain_3dmgx2_imu will not work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11583/driver-for-microstrain-3dm-gx3-35/) by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 544 on 2011-10-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are only interested in the IMU part then it is possible to set the sensor to AHRS direct mode. Then it will work with the microstrain_3dmgx2_imu driver.

---

Originally posted by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) with karma: 544 on 2011-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brianyg](https://answers.ros.org/users/23554/brianyg/) on 2015-08-28**:
Hi, I am new to ROS, could you please give me details about how to set the sensor to AHRS direct mode? THanks :)

**Comment by [PeteMakesThings](https://answers.ros.org/users/24332/petemakesthings/) on 2015-11-12**:
I would like to know how to do this as well. I have the exact same issue. I'm trying to get IMU data into ROS using the 3DM-GX3-35. The existing GX2 and GX3-45 drivers haven't worked, but I haven't tried AHRS mode.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is [a new driver](http://ros.org/wiki/microstrain_3dm_gx3_45) for this devices. Feel free to test it and report potential bugs :)

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1